# Question about do carmo exercise: regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I have studied Do Carmo diff.geometry chapeter 2.2 about regular surface.

Of course I saw all examples of textbook but cannot apply to this problem.

This is image for exercise 2.2.2, which I don't know how to solve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWdrO.png)

In my guess, I thought that only first surface is not able to become regular surface

because it is not possible to make map between open set and closed set with regular surface options.

But I don't have any specific proof and idea.

( By searching in Wikipedia, I found that homeomorphism is map from open set to open set, but I don't know how to prove it also...)

How can I solve this exercise with clarified proof??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: thanks very much!!